# Maximum number of characters in UITextField allowing deleting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` which I'd like to have a 30 character limit. I'm doing that in this way:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
                                                       replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Currently, if I enter two duplicate entries into the table these text fields are filling, our server appends `_1234` onto the end, four random numbers, to prevent duplicate names. So, for instance, if I enter `abc`, then `abc` again, the second one will be named `abc_8252`.

If I enter two duplicate 30-character names, the `_9392` is still appended, making an entry of 35 characters, and the code above falls apart because the `replacementString` will never bring it down under 30 characters.

What I'd like to do is, in the event that the string is `> 30` characters, only allow the `backspace` key, so that they can bring it back down, but not make it any longer, and once it drops below 30, won't be able to go back above it again. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it like so:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
                                                       replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Allow a backspace always, in case we went over 30 due to the _1234 appending.
    const char *_char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");
    if (isBackSpace == -8) {
        return YES;
    }

    // If it's not a backspace, allow it if we're still under 30 chars.
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
}
```